# Fantasy anime involving a village where everyone was trying to blame a young girl for a missing wedding ring

Tags: story-identification, magic, manga, isekai, reincarnation

The anime I'm looking for is a fantasy one but I hardly remember it.
The only part I remember is that there was a village and everyone was trying to blame a young girl for a missing ring but the old lady was trying to tell them that the girl didn't steal her wedding ring but no one believed the old lady.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably the second episode from *Zero kara Hajimeru Mahou no Sho* (known on Amazon prime as *The Grimoire of Zero*). Albus finds a ring in a pond; it turns out to belong to an old lady in a nearby village.  On the way to the village Albus' party is given some tomatoes by a passing farmer.  They are accused of stealing both the ring and the tomatoes.
[image]